# Wrong result printing out from application

Tags: java, println

I encountered a problem with the result that prints out. My program right now should print 2 columns side to side but for some reason one side prints way below what was intended. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

```
public class AscendDescend
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String ss[] = {"Bill", "Mary", "Lee", "Agenes", "Alfred", "Thomas", "Alvin", "Bernard", "Ezra", "Herman"};
        //String ss[] = {"Bill", "Mary", "Lee", "Agenes", "Alfred", "Thomas", "Alvin", "Bernard", "Ezra", "Herman"};

        System.out.println("Ascend\tDescend" + "\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ss[i]);
        }

        for(int j = ss.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            System.out.println("\t" + ss[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your code I can visualize it, but it would still be better if you added the wrong output. Also: please change your title!

Answer (score 3):

You are:

- printing out all the values in ascending order - each on a separate line; then
- printing out all the values in descending order - each prefixed by a tab and on a new line.

What you appear to want to do is print out both the ascending and descending items on the same line. Something like this:

```
public class AscendDescend
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String ss[] = {"Bill", "Mary", "Lee", "Agenes", "Alfred", "Thomas", "Alvin", "Bernard", "Ezra", "Herman"};

        System.out.println("Ascend\tDescend" + "\n");
        final int l = ss.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ss[i] + "\t" + ss[l-1-i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Ascend  Descend

Bill    Herman
Mary    Ezra
Lee Bernard
Agenes  Alvin
Alfred  Thomas
Thomas  Alfred
Alvin   Agenes
Bernard Lee
Ezra    Mary
Herman  Bill
```

Comment: Yes. A single loop printing both columns at once.  In the original question, you print a line for each item in the Ascend order, then print new lines afterwards in the Descend order.  It did what your code asked and kept printing new lines.  I agree with this answer for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` will print a new line. That will make the values for ascend and descend 
be not in the same line.

If you would like to print 2 columns side to side. You can just print the values for ascend and descend in the same for-loop.

Like,

```
    System.out.println("Ascend\tDescend" + "\n");

    for (int i = 0, len = ss.length; i < ss.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%s\t%s \n", ss[i], ss[len - 1 - i]);
    }
```

Then the output in console will be as follows:

```
Ascend  Descend

Bill    Herman 
Mary    Ezra 
Lee     Bernard 
Agenes  Alvin 
Alfred  Thomas 
Thomas  Alfred 
Alvin   Agenes 
Bernard Lee 
Ezra    Mary 
Herman  Bill
```